# Scroll position problem with resposive navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem with resposive navigation that i worked on.The problem is that when i open and then closed the menu it's take me back to the beginning of the page.I want when open and then closed the menu scroll position to be the same as that before opening the menu.How to make that?

HTML

```
 <header class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <h2>LOGO</h2>
      </div>
        <nav>
            <div id="mainbox" onclick="openFunction()"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
            <div id="menu" class="sidemenu">
             <a href="#">Home</a>
             <a href="#">About</a>
             <a href="#">Contact</a>
             <a href="#">Login</a>
             <a href="#" class="closebtn" onclick="closeFunction()">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
#mainbox{
 font-size: 24px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all .6s;
 display:none;

}
.sidemenu{
  background-color: #222;
  color:#999;
  float:right;

}
.sidemenu a{
 padding:20px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #999;
 display: inline-block;
}
.sidemenu a:hover{
  color: white;
}
.sidemenu .closebtn{
 position: absolute;
 top: -15px;
 right: 15px;
 font-size: 36px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 display:none;
}
.fas{
  color:#999;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-right:32px;
}
.fas:hover{
  color:white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  #mainbox{
    display:block;
    float:right;
  }
  .header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sidemenu .closebtn{display:block;}
  .sidemenu{
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    background-color: #222;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: all .5s;
    text-align: center;
   }
   .sidemenu a{
     display:block;

      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #999;
   }

}
```

Javascript

```
function openFunction(){
  document.getElementById("menu").style.width="100%";
  document.getElementById("mainbox").style.marginLeft="300px";

 }
function closeFunction(){
 document.getElementById("menu").style.width="0px";
 document.getElementById("mainbox").style.marginLeft="0px";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your href="#", just add `e.preventDefault()` to close function.

**html**

```
<a href="#" class="closebtn" onclick="closeFunction(e)">&times;</a>
```

**js**

```
function closeFunction(e){
 e = e || window.event;
 e.preventDefault()
 document.getElementById("menu").style.width="0px";
 document.getElementById("mainbox").style.marginLeft="0px";

}
```

Hope it will work for you

Comment: @Toshiro I'm happy to help you. Please click on the check mark on the left side of my answer.